# How do I convert a nested tuple of tuples and lists to lists of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a tuple containing lists and more tuples.  I need to convert it to nested lists with the same structure.  For example, I want to convert `(1,2,[3,(4,5)])` to  `[1,2,[3,[4,5]]]`.

How do I do this (in Python)?

Comment: I know the answer but I'll give you a chance to post your solution first.

Comment: And the standoff continues.....

Comment: I have a question but have to spell it backwards - ()tsil .

Comment: it will be )(tsil, dear gimel :)

Comment: S.Lott - Do you need more examples than the one I gave?  Basically I want to convert a data structure containing lists and tuples to just lists (so the representation would have '(' and ')' converted to '[' and ']'.

Comment: Previously when I've posted a question and then immediately posted an answer, there were complaints.  So I thought this time I'd leave a window for other answers first.  At least this time the commentators have a sense of humor.

Comment: Oop.  -5 votes!  Perhaps it's because I forgot to supply my own answer.

Comment: What is wrong with this question that it deserves -4 votes?

Comment: Not sure why you're being downvoted so badly. You could have posted your own attempt at the problem, but the question is valid and clearly stated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
def listit(t):
    return list(map(listit, t)) if isinstance(t, (list, tuple)) else t
```

The shortest solution I can imagine.

Comment: map() always returns a list. list(map( ... )) should be map( ... )

Comment: NicDumZ that's right if you python 2.x but in 3.x map() returns a generator.

Comment: and what's the difference from Christian's answer?

Comment: listit( ('AB') ) returns 'AB', not ['AB'] as it should.

Comment: @CPBL try listit(('AB',)) instead.  The way you wrote it, you're passing 'AB' enclosed in parentheses, instead of the single-element tuple ('AB',).

Answer (score 8):

As a python newbie I would try this

```
def f(t):
    if type(t) == list or type(t) == tuple:
        return [f(i) for i in t]
    return t

t = (1,2,[3,(4,5)]) 
f(t)
>>> [1, 2, [3, [4, 5]]]
```

Or, if you like one liners:

```
def f(t):
    return [f(i) for i in t] if isinstance(t, (list, tuple)) else t
```

Comment: When you need to check an object's type, it's better to use the isinstance() function. As a bonus, you can even check for multiple types at once, like this: isinstance(t, (list, tuple))

Comment: hasattr(t,'__iter__') perhaps

Comment: @Jimmy `hasattr(t,'iter')` is to much because str is iterable too (and you wouldn't want convert them to lists of chars, usually)

Answer (score 2):

We can (ab)use the fact that `json.loads` always produces Python lists for JSON lists, while `json.dumps` turns any Python collection into a JSON list:

```
import json

def nested_list(nested_collection):
    return json.loads(json.dumps(nested_collection))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had come up with, but I like the other's better.

```
def deep_list(x):
      """fully copies trees of tuples or lists to a tree of lists.
         deep_list( (1,2,(3,4)) ) returns [1,2,[3,4]]
         deep_list( (1,2,[3,(4,5)]) ) returns [1,2,[3,[4,5]]]"""
      if not ( type(x) == type( () ) or type(x) == type( [] ) ):
          return x
      return map(deep_list,x)
```

I see [aztek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75280/aztek)'s answer can be shortened to:

```
def deep_list(x):
     return map(deep_list, x) if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) else x
```

**Update**: But now I see from [DasIch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114920/dasich)'s comment that this wouldn't work in Python 3.x since map() there returns a generator.